# Why don't pre-create instance before return in Singleton pattern

Tags: c#, singleton

I've seen many people write singleton like this

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton _instance = null;

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Singleton();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference from this code

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton _instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

Nowaday(C# 6), we have Getter-only auto-properties, is this difference from above(I prefer to write it like this)

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();
}
```

From what I've known, static field is guaranteed to be ready before I access it for the first time, so it's nothing different, only thing that different is in the first case, I will know when instance is created.

Is there anything more than this or I misunderstand everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is called "Lazy" which postpones the creation of value to first request.
2. Create the object at the very beginning.
3. Simplified version of 2.

---

Or, you can simply use "Lazy" class which many people neglect.

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Lazy<Singleton> instance = new Lazy<Singleton>();
    public static Singleton Instance => instance.Value;
}
```

"Lazy" is good for large programs.

1. Reduce startup time since creation is postponed.
2. Save resource if eventually class is not used.

Comment: `3. Create a new object every time "Instance" is called.` it create instance only 1 time when property is called for the first time, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh you are right. I mistook it as a lambda property. Thank you. And the answer is edited.